# Unix: cat-ing a file out to itself - why does this blank the file?

Tags: bash, unix, sorting, pipe, cat

Can someone please explain to me why this code works (i.e. file2.txt is the alphabetically sorted contents of file1.txt):

```
cat file1.txt | sort > file2.txt
```

But when I do this, file1.txt blanks itself...?

```
cat file1.txt | sort > file1.txt
```

As you can guess, I'm trying to simply sort a file's contents alphabetically, then write back to the same file...

(I'm using mac 10.8.3's terminal. Date of writing is 19may2013)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shell starts `sort` after opening `file1.txt` for output (truncating it, ie discarding all the data).  Then it starts `cat` with `file1.txt` open for reading.  The semantics of the shell are such that it might be feasible for the pipeline to get a page or so of input from `file.txt`, but in practice almost all shells (which is to say all of them, but perhaps there are some shells I've never used that do not behave this way) will truncate the file before `cat` ever reads any data.

To perform this operation, you must use a temporary file.   (Well, it's not mandatory to use a temporary file.  If the file is small enough, something like this will probably work `cat file1.txt | ( sleep 2; sort > file1.txt )`, but is not guaranteed.)

Comment: @JamesThomasMoon1979 re: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12077402  I like the edit, but given the age of this answer it's probably best to let it stay as is.  Thanks for the suggestions!