# sort file.txt > file.txt is empty

Tags: bash, shell

I have a doubt about a simple command and it is because in bash if I do

```sh
sort file.txt > file.txt
```

file .txt remains empty (it shouldn't keep file.txt with what it had before but sorted) but if I do

```sh
sort file.txt >> file.txt
```

then the ordered elements are added to the previous elements.

Comment: duplicates: [why does this blank the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16634207/995714), [Why does redirecting the output of a file to itself produce a blank file?](https://superuser.com/q/597244/241386), [How can I use a file in a command and redirect output to the same file without truncating it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6696842/995714), [Why redirecting output sometimes produces an empty file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/586443/44425), [Why is the file being emptied during input/output redirection to the same file?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1289971/253474)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior.  The phrase `> file.txt` opens `file.txt` for **overwriting** before the command `sort` is even run.  So when `sort` runs it sees that `file.txt` is empty.

On the other hand, the phrase `>> file.txt` opens `file.txt` for **appending** before the command `sort` is even run.  So when `sort` runs it reads the full file and then appends the results to the file.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you targeted your file with `>` the shell truncated all the data before `sort` could read it.

```
sort file.txt > tmp.txt && mv tmp.txt file.txt
```

Comment: it's the **shell** who does the redirection and truncation. The OS has nothing to do with it

Comment: Valid - Edited.